# Why not expand Stack Overflow to allow system admin questions?

Tags: discussion, meta

As a developer I need to perform system admin tasks all the time during the process for example of setting up an ubuntu server.

I read this question on ssh setup which is "closed as off topic by symcbean, Robert Harvey♦ Jul 10 '12 at 23:48

Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421840/ssh-not-working-connection-refused

As a programmer I needed advice on SSH setup and answers to questions related to as well as other sys admin questions.

What possible logic or benefit comes to Stack Overflow by not allowing these system admin type questions?

Programming can not occur without some system admin.

Please expand your concept of what is allowed to include questions that are relevant to programming. This logically include sys admin topics.

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/ http://unix.stackexchange.com/ http://superuser.com/

Comment: Next you're going to want a whole host of other topic-driven sites on Stack Exchange.  What is the world coming to??

Answer (score 8):

StackOverflow is generally only for questions that are **only** applicable to programmers (or at least mainly applicable to them).

System admin questions are more applicable to system administrators (who are generally not programmers) and would thus be more appropriate on a site dedicated to this, such as [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/).